# In TOV equations of hydrostatic equilibrium

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, neutron-stars, stellar-physics

in TOV equations of hydrostatic equilibrium $\{P(r),M(r),v(r)\}$ are coupled with 1st order and $P(r)$ , $M(r)$ have initial values at $r=0$ but $v(r)$ is at the boundary of the star. Therefore, when we numerically integrate them due coupling of $P(r)$ and $M(r)$ in $v(r)$ the system ask for the initial value of $v(r)$ but we have only boundary condition of $v(r)$ .i.e $v(R)=\left(1-\frac{2GM}{R^2}\right)$. Is there any particular way to find the initial value of $v(r)$ i.e $v(0)=$?. Or some one have a code that result on the two initial values of $P$ and $M$ and generate the solution of $v$ at the boundary value.

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation for $\nu(r)$ is 
$$\frac{d\nu(r)}{dr}=-\frac{2}{P(r)+\rho(r)}\frac{dP(r)}{dr},$$
which happens to be independent of $\nu(r)$. Because of that fact if one has a solution $\nu_1(r)$ then $$\nu(r)=\nu_1(r)+c$$ is also a solution. So one can integrate $d\nu_1(r)/dr$ with arbitrary initial conditions, lets say $\nu_1(r=0)=42$ and then add an offset to the solution to ensure the boundary condition on the stellar surface:
$$\nu(r)=\nu_1(r)-\nu_1(R)+1-\frac{2M}{R}.$$

It is not necessary to solve a real boundary value problem with a shooting method or something like that in case of $\nu(r)$.